# Type in value in FL Studio, how should I calculate correct value?

Tags: daw, fl-studio

Let's say in DirectWave, I want to change the pitch tune using **Type in value** option, what number should I input if I want to change the pitch to -100 cents (*1 semitone lower*)?

Seems like there is some sort of black magic behind this option and using it required calculation and formula which I could not find any documentation about it.

[image]

Comment: Probably just math, not magic. :) What units are used to specify the pitch? If it’s Hertz (Hz) and you want to lower the current value by 100 cents (1 equal temperament semitone), divide the Hz by the 12th root of 2, which is about 1.059463094359295.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I don't know the unit, Hint panel shows Cents as unit. I tried `1.059463094359295` and pitch changed to -1200. it's crazy, user have to do this calc! if they can not do this weird calc, why they added this option?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot with the original value? If it’s correcting your input to -1200, then it’s probably a *change in pitch* specified in cents, not an absolute pitch. In this case, if you wanted 1 semitone lower, just enter -100.

Comment: The initial value is zero, and trust me, I tried many options, include simple ones (like -100), I tried %, 0.1, ... (before post the question here), not of them doesn't work

Comment: @trw and yes, (_in DirectWave_) 1 pitch = 100 cents. btw DirectWave and pitch is an example here. I don't know there is one global formula for `Type in value` option or every parameter have specific formula

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: @trw done! .....

Comment: And what about after you select “type in value…”?

Comment: I'm sorry bro, have you FL installed in your machine? when I select "Type in value", the textbox shows up (get value prompt), there is nothing special here, just a textbox and 2 fancy buttons (apply and cancel)